# Navigation bar only appears only when hover

Tags: css, navbar

I have been modifying a website, on which the navigation bar was working fine.
Now the same navigation bar refuses to display properly, whatever browser I use: Firfox, Safari, Opera.

The background image appears only when the mouse hovers, and the dark line that signals which page is active, appears on top of the page instead of on the button itself.

I use 3 different CSS for one website, 5 main pages, and this problem appears on every page.

The site is crossroadinnovation .com
It seems I can't post the HTML here, but here is the CSS code for the navigation bar, as well as for the "darkline":

```
/* navigation menu */
#navmenu{
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -21px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 1006px;
 height: 15px;
}
 #navmenu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 12px;
  list-style-image: none;
 }

 #navmenu li {
  list-style:none;
     float: left;
     width: 100px;
     margin: 0px auto;
     padding: 0;
  display: inline;
  width: 186px;
  height: 1%;
 }

 #navmenu li a {
  font-family: Times New Roman, Times, serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
 }


/* links mouseover effect*/
#dialogue{
 position: absolute;
 width: 185px;
 height: 15px;
 background-image: url(...);
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: hidden;
 padding: 5px;
 top: 11px;
}
#dialogue:hover{
  background: url(...);
  outline: none;
 }
#cocreation{
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 196px;
 width: 185px;
 height: 15px;
 background-image: url(...);
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: hidden;
 padding: 5px;
 top: 11px;
}
#cocreation:hover{
  background: url(...);
  outline: none;
 }
#aboutus{
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 392px;
 width: 186px;
 height: 15px;
 background-image: url(...);
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: hidden;
 padding: 5px;
 top: 11px;
}
#aboutus:hover{
  background: url(...);
  outline: none;
 }
#services{
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 589px;
 width: 186px;
 height: 15px;
 background-image: url(...);
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: hidden;
 padding: 5px;
 top: 11px;
}
#services:hover{
  background: url(...);
  outline: none;
 }

#contact{
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 786px;
 width: 186px;
 height: 15px;
 background-image: url(...);
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: hidden;
 padding: 5px;
 top: 11px;
}

 #contact:hover{
  background: url(...);
  outline: none;
 }




/*Darkline on link -active page */
#darkline {
 z-index: 10;
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
}

#darkline_dialogue{
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 12px;
 margin-top: 11px;
 width: 195px;
 height: 2px;
 background-image: url(...);

}

#darkline_cocreation{
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 208px;
 margin-top: 11px;
 width: 195px;
 height: 2px;
 background-image: url(...);

}

#darkline_aboutus{
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 404px;
 margin-top: 11px;
 width: 196px;
 height: 2px;
 background-image: url(...);

}

#darkline_services{
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 601px;
 margin-top: 11px;
 width: 196px;
 height: 2px;
 background-image: url(...);

}

#darkline_contact{
 position: fixed;
 margin-left: 798px;
 margin-top: 11px;
 width: 196px;
 height: 2px;
 background-image: url(...);

}
```

Comment: Does anyone have an idea how to solve that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can we get some HTML with that CSS?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Nobody can know what you get from a CSS file.

What is your HTML, what do you get, and what do you need to get?

Comment: people at SO are actually living CSS parsers, don't you know that? :) Come on, it's just like 200 lines, not too hard to visualize... XD

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answers, and I am sorry to be so confusing. First day on SO...

I forgot to mention that this CSS is applied to a Wordpress site. Therefore I can't edit the HTML.
(and it seems like I can't post it here either :).
But here is the site: crossroadinnovation.com

I get a button that disappear, unless the mouse hovers it.
I need to get 5 buttons, aligned, with a darkline at the bottom of each of them, when the page is active.

Comment: Maintenance mode is removed now...

Comment: Does anyone see what i mean...?